# My images are not showing up after importing to Pantheon

Tags: 7, database, media

I finished creating my drupal site with WAMP and then imported the database. None of my images are showing up. I am assuming this is a file-path problem, but i'm not quite sure how to fix it?

For example, I have a image field in a content type, but it does not tell me where / how I can edit or change the pathing file.

Answer (score 1):

By default, images uploaded through an image field are saved to the sites/default/files folder and not the database. Be sure that you have also imported your /files folder into your new site and the images should show up without needing any changes to file paths.